# Swap split system head unit

Tags: plumbing, hvac, compressor

We have a Daikin split system, 1x compressor and 3x head units, connected like this:

[image]

The head units are pretty ancient (models FTK35HVEA and FTK25HVEA), but the main issue is the vanes do not swing any lower than horizontal (the air gets blown up high around the ceiling, instead of downwards onto people.

Therefore I would like to know:

- Can I replace just one of the head units?
- Can I use any brand/model head unit or would it need to be Daikin? Are the pipes and wiring compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't **know** but I'd strongly doubt you can use a different brand successfully, or possibly even a much newer one from the same brand if they have not deliberately designed them to  remain compatible over time as models change...

Comment: Keep in mind any such work will involve refrigerant, and so will require a qualified person *with the vampire equipment to recover freon*, and the supply chain connections so they can take the recovered freon in to have it re-purified or destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting an answer from Daikin: **not possible**. There's a couple reasons:

- PCB communication is different
- Newer indoor units communicate on feed 3 instead of 2 like the older ones
- My system runs on R22 gas - newer ones run on R32

I guess it's possible to find a second-hand, similar aged, compatible head unit but I'm just going to learn to live with these.

Comment: In order to adjust the airflow direction a [vent deflector](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/611918/611918068602.jpg?size=md) might help. This is one example, I'm sure there are others that won't turn the air a full 90°, or you could make one similar and less cheesy looking than the manila file folder I've often seen used in offices. (The ladies get cold sitting directly under vents and have someone tape up a folder to direct the cold air away from them.)